# ActionBarSherlock casues distortion of other views and it doesn't display correctly

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I use the newest ActionBarSherlock extension of the support library in my application. I came across a weird appearance of the views and action bar itself when I ran an app on emulator 4.2 and device with android 4.2 Please take a look at the screenshots from the emulator. We can see that blue line appears in every line separator in the ListView and underline the home icon.[image]

Also the little right arrow is underline and not scaled properly as well.
And to put that in perspective, it display well in emulator with android 2.2

The way I use the Theme is:

ManifestFile.xml:

```
android:theme="@style/AppThemeWithoutTitle"
```

and styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppThemeWithoutTitle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
  <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarWithoutTitle</item>
  <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarWithoutTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarWithoutTitle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
  <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
</style>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar` isn't a theme, it's a style. The first clue is it starts with `Widget`. The convention for themes in Android is to start it with the word `Theme` or at least put the word `Theme` in the name of the style.

The style you overrode and tried to use as a Theme is the style assigned to `actionBarStyle` which is the very thing you are trying to override.

You need to have an actual theme as your parent, then, and only then can you override `actionBarStyle` and have it work.

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/bg_striped</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_striped</item>

    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/bg_striped_split</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/bg_striped_split</item>
</style>
```

You can find all the available themes you can override [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/library/res/values/abs__themes.xml).

Comment: Thanks. I have messed up with the styles.